# How to make screenreader read different text in div

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a div like this: 
`<div class="whatever">17:03</div>`

And when someone using a screen reader hovers over that text, I'd like it to read "17 minutes and 3 seconds"

What's the standard practice for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just making the English text the Aria Label, as this div was inside of an `<a>` tag, so its information ended up being read by the screenreader when it was in the aria label, without creating any extra tab targets.

Comment: Where did you put the `aria-label`?  On the `<div>` or the `<a>`?  It won't work if on the `<div>` but should be ok if on the `<a>`.

Comment: I don't work at YouTube anymore unfortunately, so I can't reference the code to check, but I assume it was on the <a> directly. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 7):

You can include some additional text for screenreader only:

```
<div class="whatever">17<span class="sr-only"> minutes and </span>:03<span class="sr-only">seconds</span></div>
```

and CSS (taken from Bootstrap 3)

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
```